# I got wrong return in php division

Tags: php

i want to get the exact answer of this two number which is 0.00001950899
but this gives me 1.9508993743661E-5.

```
    $n1 = 1;
    $n2 = 51258.4100;
    $value = $n1/$n2;
    echo  $value ;
```

how i will get the exact answer?

Comment: What's 1.9508993743661 * 10^-5?

Comment: $value = 1.9508993743661E-5.

Comment: `E` stands for ` * 10^`

Comment: use `echo sprintf('%f', $value);`

Comment: i dont understand sir sorry, can u help me get the result 0.00001950899 ? when i divide that two number

Comment: PHP isn't giving you an incorrect answer, it's just giving it in another form

Comment: echo sprintf('%f', $value); gives me 0.000020

Comment: how do i get the correct answer ?

Comment: You have the correct a answer. Look at     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting right value but still you can format it using `number_format`

```
$n1 = 1;
$n2 = 51258.4100;
$value = $n1/$n2;
echo  number_format((float)$value, 20, '.', ''); //show a number to 20 decimal places
```

It will gives you 0.00001950899374366080